# embed video from 4shared played with jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer

I'm using JW-Player to play videos hosted on 4shared.com but the problem is, when i'm not logged on 4shared.com the jw-player doesn't work because 4shared.com is require to be logged in to play the videos.

My question is : Is there any posibility to play the 4shared.com videos from my blog with embed code using jwplayer and without to be registred or logged in 4shared.com ?

Comment: We don't have any official integration with 4Shared. I know that 4Shared itself uses the JW Player for their embeds though. The only 3rd party source that we officially support is YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
You need 4shared video api.

```
http://www.4shared.com/developer/docs/
```

Or
Use Curl

[> This May Help You](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216322/use-php-to-get-embed-src-page-information)